# import "moment/moment" is not ignoring "moment/locale"

Tags: javascript, angular, import, momentjs

I am using `moment.js` library in my angular project. And I do not need `moment/locale` entirely from `moment.js`. So I simply imported as following :

```
import * as moment from 'moment/moment';
```

But when I analyse the vendor***.bundle.js.map which is created during build using [source-map-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer)

I still see that `moment/locale` is bundled in vendor file. And which is around ~160kb. That's huge.

Any suggestions to improve the `import` statement?

Comment: Think they are working on it https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2416

Comment: @HarryNinh Yes.The exact problem is https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2416#issuecomment-298291913